# Prove $\int_a^c f(x)dx = \int_c^b f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> If $f$ is an integrable function, then there exists $c\in[a,b]$ s.t. $\int_a^c f(x)dx = \int_c^b f(x)dx$

I tried constructing a function $g(x) = \int_a^x f(x)dx - \int_x^b f(x)dx$ and then using Bolzano's theorem: there exists a point $c$ which $g(c)=0$. We know that $g$ is continuous since both $\int_a^x f(x)dx, \int_x^b f(x)dx$ are continuous.

The problem is on how to show that $$g(a)=- \int_a^b f(x)dx<0<\int_a^b f(x)dx=g(b),$$
so that we can apply Bolzano's theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g(a) <> 0$ then either $g(a)<0<g(b)$ or $g(a)>0>g(b)$. In both cases Bolzano's theorem can be applied to conclude that there is a $c$ where $a<c<b$ and $g(c)=0$.

And if $g(a)=0$ then take $c=a$.

Answer (score 0):

how about defining:
$$F(x)=\int_0^xf(y)\,dy$$
then we have:
$$LHS=F(c)-F(a)$$
$$RHS=F(b)-F(c)$$
and for the two sides to be equal we want:
$$2F(c)=F(a)+F(b)\Rightarrow F(c)=\frac{F(a)+F(b)}{2}$$
so we now want to prove that $\exists c\in(a,b)\,s.t.\,F(c)=\frac{F(a)+F(b)}{2}$.

now since we know that $f$ is integrable over $[a,b]$ we also know that $F\in C([a,b])$ and so we can use Rolle's theorem to prove that such a point exists

Comment: Perhaps simpler is just to use the intermediate value theorem, instead of defining some auxillary function.

Comment: @A.ThomasYerger yes true

Answer (score 0):

Using your own idea, but with a proper dummy variable of integration (which should be different from the limits of integration), you can use Bolzano theorem.
So
$$ g(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt  - \int_x^b f(t)dt$$

$$ g(b) = -g(a)$$

Applying Bolzano theorem for the continuous function $g(x)$, there must be a point in between (or possibly in the boundaries), for which the value of function is zero.